# Remap two keys for one application only

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xkb

I am using [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/) to connect remotely to a Mac. Unforunately NoMachine doesn't provide a way to map keys on it's own.

While I am using NoMachine I'd like to swap my Control and 'Meta' (Windows) keys. That will mean pressing control on my keyboard will result in command (`⌘`) key being sent to the Mac so I can copy paste properly.

What is the simplest way to do this? I have seen large tutorials for XKB but no simple guide to do this for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but perhaps it may help https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings

Comment: Are you fine with running a script before and after your use of NoMachine? if so you might get mileage out of `setxkbmap -layout us,us  -option "ctrl:swap_rwin_rctl, ctrl:swap_lwin_lctl"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ideally I'd like it to be based on the window my cursor is currently in (I believe that's possible) since I regularly want to copy something from one window into no machine, which would require pressing `super` in Ubuntu and `ctrl` in nomachine. Ideally I'd like to be able to use `ctrl` both times as if I was copying natively.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer: once you remapped *a different keyboard than your default one* (I don't know how to remap to be honest), go to Settings > Region & Language > Input sources. You will find your two keyboard listed.

Go to Options above the keyboards list and select "Allow different sources for each window".

Once you open NoMachine for the first time, switch to your second keyboard, and that's it! That keyboard will work only when you open NoMachine.